# Change view before playing sound in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, view, audio, wav

I have a program which plays two sounds. I want the user to know which sound is being played, so I have two large images of buttons. I have three different views that I would like to swap between - one where both buttons are red (nothing is playing), and two where one of the two buttons is green (to show which is playing).

The main problem I am getting is that my sound plays and finishes before the view has swapped! (I am using [window setContentView:firstSound] before the sounds are played)

The altered view eventually does show up, but only after the method playing the wavs has finished.

I am playing the sound files using NSSound (they are both short wav files, so I thought it appropriate)

Anyone know what I have done wrong? Or if there is another way I could do this? Thanks heaps!!

Edit: I have followed the advice to make it so that only the image is changed (rather than the view), but the same problem occurs. The update happens after the sounds have finished playing.

Here's the code:

`-(void)readWavs{`

```
//[window setContentView:firstWav];

[redButton setHidden:YES];

NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fish" ofType:@"wav"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:YES];
[sound play];
sleep(3); //needed so that the sound will actually play
[sound stop];
[sound release];


//[redButton setHidden:NO];
//[window setContentView:testView];

sleep(2);

//[window setContentView:secondWav];

NSString *resourcePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fish" ofType:@"wav"];
NSSound *sound2 = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath2 byReference:YES];
[sound2 play];
sleep(3);
[sound2 stop];
[sound2 release];
```

}

The green 'on' button should show up before the sound plays, but it only does so after the method is done.

Comment: It might help to post the code that plays the sounds and swaps the views.

Comment: Sure thing :) I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the run loop with those `sleep()`s. The display isn't updated until all the processing for the current event is finished, and that doesn't happen until this `readWavs` method is finished.

If you want to do something after the sound is finished, assign it a delegate (probably the same object that started the sound) and implement the [NSSoundDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/NSSoundDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) `-sound:didFinishPlaying:` method. Then, in `readWavs`, just start the sound and return - your delegate method will be called when it finishes, and because `readWavs` returns immediately, it won't block the run loop.

Comment: What about if I wanted it to occur before and while the sounds are being played, and not after? (Also, I figured the sleeps were dodgy - but the sounds would run into each other if I didn't)

Comment: But you *do* want to do something after a sound has finished - start the next sound. That's the point; you use the run loop to get notified when each sound has finished, instead of blocking it with `sleep()`. Hide the red button, then start the first sound. When you get the `-sound:didFinishPlaying:` for that one, show the red button and start the second sound. And so on...

Comment: Heya - I've done what you have suggested and it definitely works (the sounds are playing their full length now) but I am still having image problems. It usually only does one change and then never changes again. I have readWavs calling playSound1 -> which plays the sound, hides the red and sets the delegate. Then the delegate calls playsSound2, which shows the previous red button and hide the other one (but this does not work).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you remember to `[sound2 setDelegate:self]`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but what it sounds like you are trying to switch to a whole different view when a sound is played that displays which sound is being played (by images)? If so, you should just use imageView.hidden = YES and imageView.hidden = NO to display the correct images based on the sound. Better yet, you could use one image view and change the image displayed in the image view based on the sound.

Comment: Haha, that would be a very logical way to go about it! xD I'll try to do that now :)

Comment: Heya, it still has the same problem. I'm just going to put my code up in the original post now.